# GraphQL AttributeError: module 'graphene' has no attribute 'Heroes'

Tags: django, graphql, graphiql, graphene-django

i am a beginner with Django & GraphQL, i had a problem the at first step, i can not reach to GraphiQL, i had an error

```
Could not import 'traindjango.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 'SCHEMA'.
AttributeError: module 'graphene' has no attribute 'Heroes'.
```

**traindjango/heroes/schema.py**

```
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from .models import Heroes


class HeroesType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Heroes


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    heroes = graphene.Heroes(HeroesType)

    def resolve_links(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Heroes.objects.all()
```

**traindjango/traindjango/schema.py**

```
import graphene

import heroes.schema


class Query(heroes.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

**traindjango/traindjango/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'heroes',
    'graphene_django',
]

GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA' : 'traindjango.schema.schema',
}
```

**traindjango/heroes/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Heroes(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Name') 
    power = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    city  = models.TextField(max_length=100, verbose_name='City' ,null=True, blank=True)
```

Could you please help me what i can do it?

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
heroes = graphene.Heroes(HeroesType)
```

You need

```
heroes = graphene.List(HeroesType)
```

`Heroes` is your model, and does not belong to Graphene.

Then you need to rename `resolve_links` as `resolve_heroes`

P.S. Good practice is to name your django modules in the singular, i.e. Hero, not Heroes. You can set the verbose name for the plural in `Meta` if it's not just adding an 's'.